# How to display message from message.properties after updating record on UI

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

I m using `Spring MVC` in `Java` and cannot able to display message from `messages.properties` in different languages as soon as any record get updated on UI (grid view PQGrid JQuery).

I tried this following code in `JSP`:

1. `<spring:message code="display.message" var="displayMessage" message="${displayMessage}"></spring:message>`
2. `<spring:message code="message.display" var="displayMessage" />
   <input type="hidden" title="${displayMessage}" />`

In the first case, I m getting error as :

```
Cannot convert `my string` of type class java.lang.String to interface org.springframework.context.MessageSourceResolvable
```

In the second case, I m not any getting any message on browser

Here is my Java code in the post method:

```
redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("displayMessage", env.getProperty("display.message"));`
```

Someone please help me.
I googled a lot. But those codes are not working for me.

Comment: Can I expect answer?

Answer (score 0):

use below code, once u update the table you have to refresh the table to get it updated

```
 $("#_gridname").pqGrid('refreshView'); or `$("#grid_json").pqGrid("refresh");
```